# Reusing values from SELECT in second result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to reuse a small part of the results of a `SELECT` in a second resultset. I have a standard select:

```
SELECT 
    o.id,
    r.my_flag,
    c.*
FROM original o
    INNER JOIN registry r ON o.id = r.id
    LEFT JOIN content c ON o.id = c.id
    --etc.
```

I need it to continue returning all of its results in the first resultset.

But I also want the `o.id` column values from this set, just where the column `r.my_flag = 1`. I need these values to get information from another table, so that I can return a second resultset using a final query. The flag is set on less than half of the results. I could:

1. Check the flag on the client and query for the second set of results separately.
2. Paste the above query into the final query, and adjust it to fetch just the flagged rows.
3. Add an `INSERT INTO #temp` at the top of the above query, which stops it from returning a result set. Then I would `SELECT * FROM #temp`, and then join to `#temp` in the final query.

---

For example, here is what that third option would look like:

```
INSERT INTO #temp
--above select here

SELECT * FROM #temp -- this returns exactly the original resultset

-- but now I can now return a second resultset:
SELECT 
    t.id,
    s.*
FROM #temp t
    INNER JOIN special s
WHERE 
    t.my_flag = 1
```

---

I've tried these options, and they are slow. This might be unavoidable. But it seems like there should be another option: conditionally collecting `id` into a variable, during that original select - similar to an `OUTPUT INTO` clause, but which works with `SELECT`.

Is there anything that can put just those `id`s from the first query (where `x.my_flag = 1`) into a variable, or can I abuse anything for the same effect?

Comment: Common Table Expression?

Comment: Could you please add a sample scenario with some data and the expected output?

Comment: Depending on actual usage, then I'd actually just do that filtering in the code layer instead of doing almost similar query twice.

Comment: @Shnugo What other info would help you answer the question? Almost any join you want will work, and even 0 joins are fine. For example, the original table has values (id, my_flag) ((123, 1), (456, 0)); the first select should return both rows. After the first query completes, there must exist a table variable containing the value 123.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it: What are you doing with the result set? Where/for what are you needing any value later? If you do a select on the table you mention in your comment (`SELECT id,my_flag FROM tbl`), then you'll get a result set with both rows. How/Where do you want to use the 123  after the query?

Comment: @Shnugo The first result set is returned to the client. I don't want that to change. If I have a table variable (with the value 123), I can then join to it in a second query, which will return a second result set to the client. But see the added code. Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: What is actually taking time?  If that is the actual query it should be very fast and running it a second time with  my_flag = 1 even faster as lots of stuff would be in memory.  How long does select count(*) .... take?

Answer (score 1):

one query and parse out the results in the client?

```
select orig.*, more.*
  from orig 
  left outer join more
        on more.id = orig.id 
       and           orig.flag = 1  
 order by orig.id
```

OP stated more.id is not unique
If orig.id is unique or there combination of unique in orig then you could still parse on the client and do it in one query

What is the actual problem here? What part is taking the time?  We might be  in an XY where you have a perceived solution and there is a better fix to the actual problem.

Hard to help you with the limited information you provide.  Here is one last try.

```
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT o.id, r.my_flag
FROM original o
INNER JOIN registry r ON o.id = r.id 
ORDER BY (o.id)   -- please tell me you have PK on #temp

SELECT * 
FROM #temp 
LEFT JOIN content c ON #temp.id = c.id

-- but now I can now return a second resultset:
SELECT t.id, s.*
FROM #temp t
INNER JOIN special s
-- please tell me this has an on clause 
WHERE 
    t.my_flag = 1
```

Comment: So this would denormalize `orig`, where each row would appear multiple times per join to `more`? I'll have a look at this, but `orig` has ntext etc. which might not like being duplicated. Thanks!

Comment: I was assuming more.id was unique.  You did call it id.

Comment: re your above comment: count() takes 12 seconds; returning all rows in the normal way is 33 seconds (2mil rows returned). Copying that result into a temp table before returning adds an additional ~5 seconds. I'm hoping to avoid most of those 5 seconds by copying only 1 column, of only those rows with the flag set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you trying to `SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM original x  WHERE x.my_flag = 1` and then `CREATE INDEX` on the columns which you will use for joining on. If you use your ID-column to join you could do a `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX`.

Comment: If I add `INTO #tmp`, that first select no longer returns a result set to the client. (Incidentally, adding an index, clustered or not, actually slows down the query).

Comment: @mk. If adding an index is slowing things down then you are adding the wrong index.